# Cockroachdb format datetime in select query

Tags: cockroachdb, sql-timestamp

I'm trying to format a timestamp value to `yyyymmdd` in cockroach DB select query.

In MySQL, we can format a date using `DATE_FORMAT()`

E.g. `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") FROM users` to fetch result into a desired format.

What would be an alternative of `DATE_FORMAT()` we can use in cockroach DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the experimental builtin [`experimental_strftime`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/functions-and-operators.html#date-and-time-functions) which uses the [strftime](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) syntax.

```
SELECT experimental_strftime(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM users
```

Alternatively, you can use `experimental_strptime` which uses the [strptime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) syntax.

Please take the time to read the important notes about [experimental features](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/experimental-features.html). The time formatting builtins are experimental because they behave differently on different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I am using golang, gorm and cockroachdb. I tried `experimental_strftime`.But it creates invalid query.

```
query := `SELECT experimental_strftime(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM users`
var version []string
rows, err := store.DB.Raw(query).Rows()
if err != nil {
    return version, err
}
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(&version)
    return version, err
}
```

Query generated in debug mode is
`SELECT experimental_strftime(created_at, '%!Y(MISSING)-%!m(MISSING)-%!d(MISSING)') FROM users`